# Position Fixed Sidebar Content Moves on Bootstrap Modal Close

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap

We have an simple React application with a basic sidebar & a bootstrap modal.
[image: With Modal Open]
And here is where we are observing strange behavior. If we click the "X" our sidebar drops down the page just for a moment until the modal closes.
[image: With Modal Open after "X" MouseDown]
This behavior is not observed with any other button or input. Even if we click the "Close" button, which does the same thing (closes the modal), the sidebar does not move. It only moves when we mousedown on the "X".

If I mouse down on the "X" and move my cursor away, then mouse up, the sidebar remains in the "moved down" state, until I close the modal.

This is very strange and we have no idea what could be going on here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code for the React Component:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState, FC } from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { BoxSeam, House, Check2Circle, Download } from 'react-bootstrap-icons'
import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalContext'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Snackbar from '../components/Snackbar'
import SelectLocationModal from '../components/SelectLocationModal'
import IPropsWithChildren from '../ts/interfaces/IPropsWithChildren.interface'
import INavLink from '../ts/interfaces/INavLink.interface'
import styles from '../styles/layouts/Layout.module.scss'

const PrivateLayout: FC<IPropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => {
    // Sidebar default is closed below 768px screens & open on larger
    // Therefore, isSidebarOpen is only an appropriate name for smaller screens
    // On larger screens this would be interpreted as isSidebarClosed
    const [isSidebarOpen, setIsSidebarOpen] = useState(false);
    const { location, setLocation } = useContext(GlobalContext);
    const navLinks: INavLink[] = [
        {
            to: '/',
            icon: <BoxSeam />,
            displayText: 'Containers',
            disabled: false
        },
        {
            to: '/receiving',
            icon: <Download />,
            displayText: "Receiving",
            disabled: false
        },
        {
            to: '/approve',
            icon: <Check2Circle />,
            displayText: "Approve",
            disabled: false
        }
    ]

    const closeOnSmScreen = () => {
        setIsSidebarOpen(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const location = localStorage.getItem('LocationID');
        if (location) {
            setLocation(location);
        }
    }, [setLocation])

    return (
        <div>
            <SelectLocationModal    
                isOpen={location === ''} 
                handleClose={() => null}
            />

            <Header 
                setIsSidebarOpen={setIsSidebarOpen} 
                isSidebarOpen={isSidebarOpen} 
            />

            <div className={styles.wrapper}>
                <nav className={`${styles.sidebar} ${isSidebarOpen ? styles.active : ''} bg-light`}>
                    <div className={styles.sidebarContent}>
                        <ul className="ps-0">
                            {
                                navLinks.map((navLink, i) => (
                                    <li key={i}>
                                        <NavLink 
                                            to={ navLink.to }
                                            activeClassName={ navLink.disabled ? '' : styles.activeLink }
                                            className={`${navLink.disabled ? styles.disabledLink : ''} d-flex align-items-center flex-md-column py-2 navLink`}
                                            onClick={closeOnSmScreen}
                                            exact
                                        >
                                            {navLink.icon}
                                            <span>{navLink.displayText}</span>
                                        </NavLink>
                                    </li>
                                ))
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div className={"childrenContainer container"}>
                    {children}
                    <Snackbar />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PrivateLayout
```

And the CSS:

```
@import '../variables.scss';

.childrenContainer {
    padding-top: $headerHeight;
}

.activeLink {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: $primary;
}

// Sidebar
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: $headerHeight;
    z-index: 999;
    min-width: 85vw;
    min-height: calc(100vh - #{$headerHeight}); 
    margin-left: -85vw;
    transition: .2s ease-in;
}

.sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px 0px #000;
}

.sidebarContent {
    position: sticky;
    li {
        list-style: none;
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: var(--dark);
        }
    }
}


.disabledLink {
    text-decoration: line-through !important;
}

.navLink {
    padding-left: 1rem;
    span {
        padding-left: .5rem;
    }
    svg {
        height: 1.25rem;
        width: 1.25rem;    
    }
}


@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .childrenContainer {
        padding-top: $headerLgHeight;
    }

    .sidebar {
        position: sticky;
        padding-top: $headerLgHeight;
        margin-left: 0;
        max-width: $sidebarWidth;
        min-width: $sidebarWidth;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .sidebar.active {
        margin-left: -$sidebarWidth;
        box-shadow: none;
        background: white !important;
    }

    .sidebarContent {
        position: fixed;
        width: $sidebarWidth;
    }

    .navLink {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        padding-left: 0;
        span {
            padding-left: 0;
            font-size: .67rem;
        }
        svg {
            height: 1.25rem;
            width: 1.25rem;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a [code snadbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-mclaren-0g3gqu?file=/src/PrivateLayout.jsx) that reproduces the behavior described above (thanks Igor Gonak for initiating this).

Comment: The provided code is a mess. Hrader, Snackbar, SelectLocationModal, GlobalContext are all not included. In the scss file you import variables file, which you don't provide. Please provide a MINIMAL working code example, where this problem is reproducible. I would love to help.

Comment: Hi @IgorGonak. Appreciate the comment. Didn't want to clog up the question with loads of unrelated react code. Ultimately, this is a css question and all css related to the sidebar is included (as well as the component where the css is implemented). Additionally, including the scss variables does not seem to be of much benefit. Colors are colors, height & width are simply values in rem.

Comment: I tried to create a minimal example, but I had to comment out many many things and the layout/css seems to be broken: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-water-67x2qt. Again, it's not my task - if you want help, please create a minified example, which reproduces the behaviour. I'm afraid otherwise no one can/will help you :/

Comment: Hi @IgorGonak. Thanks for following up on this. I have updated the codesandbox you started to reproduce the behavior I am seeing. If you click the open modal button at the bottom, the sidebar content will jump down. https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-mclaren-0g3gqu?file=/src/PrivateLayout.jsx

Comment: Thank you so much for working code sandbox. It makes the life so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove "top" and it stops flipping:

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    // top: $headerHeight;
    z-index: 999;
    min-width: 85vw;
    min-height: calc(100vh - #{$headerHeight}); 
    margin-left: -85vw;
    transition: .2s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Igor! This pointed me in the right direction. This actually pertained to the code in the media query (it was only an issue on larger screens). I actually had to change `.sidebar` to `position: fixed`, then add conditional padding-left equal to the $sidebarWidth (depending if sidebar is open) to the `.childrenContainer`.